# How to do integration testing of Jaxrs Resource?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, integration-testing

I am designing Rest API using jax-rs and want to do integration testing of end point.
For that, I am using following piece of code.

Service Layer

```
public class TimeService {
    public long time() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Resource Layer

```
@Path("/time")
@Produces("text/plain")
public class TimeResource {
    
    @Inject
    private TimeService timeService;
    
    @GET
    public String getTime() {
        System.out.println(timeService.time());
        return new Date().toString();
    }
}
```

Now for test, if I do setup like below code then it throws error.
First version for test setup.

```
public class TimeResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(TimeService.class);
        config.register(TimeResource.class);
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTime() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        Response response = target("/time").request().get();
        assertEquals("Http Response should be 200: ", Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}

Sep 19, 2023 8:16:57 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=TimeService,parent=TimeResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,409632731)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
```

Second version of test setup. If I do setup like this then error is different.

```
public class TimeResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(TimeService.class);
                bind(TimeResource.class);
            }
        });
        return config;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnTime() throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        Response response = target("/time").request().get();
        assertEquals("Http Response should be 200: ", Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}

java.lang.AssertionError: Http Response should be 200:  expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
    at
```

Can someone tell, which is the correct approach to setup test and how to resolve related error ?

Comment: It should be `config.register(TimeResource.class)`. The `TimeService` is correct with the `AbstractBinder`